# to execute a link using curl

Tags: php, curl, hyperlink

i am trying to execute a link (without page being redirected) using curl.
see below my code...

```
$ch = curl_init(); // Initializing
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim("http://api.smsgatewayhub.com/smsapi/pushsms.aspx?user=stthomasmtc&pwd=429944&to=9176411081&sid=STMTSC&msg=Dear Sam,%20choir%20practice%20will%20be%20held%20in%20our%20Church%20on%20July%2031%20at%208:00%20pm.%20Thanks,%20St.%20Thomas%20MTC!&fl=0&gwid=2")); // Set URI
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://api.smsgatewayhub.com/smsapi/pushsms.aspx?user=stthomasmtc&pwd=429944&to=9176411081&sid=STMTSC&msg=Dear Sam,%20choir%20practice%20will%20be%20held%20in%20our%20Church%20on%20July%2031%20at%208:00%20pm.%20Thanks,%20St.%20Thomas%20MTC!&fl=0&gwid=2"); // Set URI
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); //Set Header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300); // Time-out in seconds
$result = curl_exec($ch); // Executing
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($httpCode != 200) {
    $result = ""; // Executing
}
curl_close($ch); // Closing the channel
return $result;
```

but i get the response as Bad Request. 
when i try to change the url to www.google.com, it seems executing. When i manually use this link in browser, its executed as expected - to send message to me. let me know if there is a better way to execute a link without page being redirected...

Comment: Careful, you're exposing your `user` and `pwd` combination and the service url to the Internet. Are you sure this is not sensitive data?

Comment: i have changed it in a short while :))
i've been desperate to get an answer :(

Comment: The login info is invalid, if you already knew that, good, if not, try it with the correct user/pass. also, urlencode your parameters.

Comment: any guidance plz... :(

Answer (score -1):

This maybe a very old question. But since it has gone unanswered and pops up in Google when you say SMSGatewayHub + SO, I'll go ahead and present an alternative.

Get the class https://github.com/adarshdec23/SMSGatewayhub. It works with both promotional and transactional SMS messages.

Here is a [step by step guide](http://adarsha.xyz/send-sms-via-php-using-smsgatewayhub/) to using it.
It uses an API key instead of your username and password. Once you're done with that, the class makes an API call (without cURL). Its simple and gets the job done.

Comment: has nothing to do with ops question